# Laravel custom rate limiter not triggering

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have created a custom rate limiter in my RouteServiceProvider.php but it doesnt seem to be working;

This is part of my RouteServiceProvider;

```php
public function boot(): void
{
    $this->configureRateLimiting();
}

protected function configureRateLimiting(): void
{
    RateLimiter::for('customweb', function (Request $request) {
        Limit::perHour(5)->by(optional($request->user())->id ?: $request->ip())->response(function () {
            return view('login')->with([
                'error' => 'Youve tried too many times'
            ]);
        });
    });
}
```

My web route looks like so;

```php
Route::post('login', AuthLoginController::class)
    ->middleware('throttle:customweb');
```

It should trigger after 5 tries, but no matter how many times i try, it just runs the login functionality.

Comment: you are not returning from the closure for the call to `for` btw

Comment: @lagbox .. Ok, I added the return and its now registering, but i am getting the following now `Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException::__construct(): Argument #1 ($response) must be of type Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response, Illuminate\View\View given`

Comment: "If you would like to define your own response that should be returned by a rate limit, you may use the `response` method:" - [defining rate limiters](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#defining-rate-limiters) `return response()->view(...);` [view responses](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#view-responses)